# How to get attributes of parameter I am trying to bind to in IModelBinder?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

Is there a way to access the attributes of the controller action parameter currently being processed from within `IModelBinder.BindModel()`?

In particular, I am writing a binder for binding request data to an arbitrary `Enum` type (specified as a template parameter to the model binder) and I would like to specify for each controller action parameter for which I want to use this binder a name of the HTTP request value to get the `Enum` values from.

Example:

```
public ViewResult ListProjects([ParseFrom("jobListFilter")] JobListFilter filter)
{
    ...
}
```

and the model binder:

```
public class EnumBinder<T>  : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext,
                            ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        HttpRequestBase request = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request;

        // Get the ParseFrom attribute of the action method parameter
        // From the attribute, get the FORM field name to be parsed
        //
        string formField = GetFormFieldNameToBeParsed();

        return ConvertToEnum<T>(ReadValue(formField));
    }
}
```

I suspect there may possibly be another, more appropriate, point in the request workflow where I would supply the attribute value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found out how to do it using `CustomModelBinderAttribute`-derived class:

```
public class EnumModelBinderAttribute : CustomModelBinderAttribute
{
    public string Source { get; set; }
    public Type EnumType { get; set; }

    public override IModelBinder GetBinder()
    {
        Type genericBinderType = typeof(EnumBinder<>);
        Type binderType = genericBinderType.MakeGenericType(EnumType);

        return (IModelBinder) Activator.CreateInstance(binderType, this.Source);
    }
}
```

Now the action method looks like this:

```
public ViewResult ListProjects([EnumModelBinder(EnumType=typeof(JobListFilter), Source="formFieldName")] JobListFilter filter)
{
    ...
}
```